# Memoir: no space after section heading

Tags: spacing, sectioning, memoir

How do I set zero space after a section heading using `memoir.cls`? If I use the following:

```
\setbeforesubsubsecskip{-\baselineskip}
\setaftersubsubsecskip{0pt}
```

I get a run-in heading. This is only supposed to happen when the specified skip is negative. Currently, I have

```
\setbeforesubsubsecskip{-\baselineskip}
\setaftersubsubsecskip{0.0001pt}
```

but that feels rather hackish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the [LaTeX 2e sources](http://www.tug.org/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf), p. 283 (regarding the `\@startsection` command):

> **afterskip:** if positive, then skip to
>   leave below heading, else negative of
>   skip to leave to right of run-in
>   heading

In other words, a run-in heading *is* supposed to happen if the specified skip is exactly zero.

I suggest to use `\setaftersubsubsecskip{1sp}` -- it is a hack, but you're in good company. You may also switch to the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/titlesec.html) package which allows for zero and negative afterskips that don't create run-in headings -- but titlesec might break other memoir features.

Comment: 1sp should be sufficiently small not to be noticed, but still... And on the negativity of zero, that's debatable of course. The official definition is that it's neither, which makes the definition of _afterskip_ above ambiguous.

Comment: It is LaTeX tradition from the kernel, and we follow it in memoir. BTW: In the recent memoir a non-zero `\parskip` no longer effect the spacing around the titles.

Comment: @Michel If you read what lockstep put carefully, it doesn't treat 0 as negative, but merely as not positive.

Comment: titlesec should work with memoir as long as _all_ your title fiddling is done through titlesec. You can't mix and match, but somewhere in `memman.pdf` it does say that it is compatible with titlesec.